# Dll Config not being recognized

Tags: c#, configuration, config, app-config, configuration-files

I'm working on a `dll` (**MyExtension.dll**) that will be an extension for a host application. When the host application launches it recognizes the dll and makes the functionality available to the user. My `dll` has a `.config` file (**MyExtension.dll.config**) that sits beside the `dll`. In the config file I have various sections for some settings. A simplified example is below:

```xml
<configSections>
        <section name="categories" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
</configSections>

<categories>
        <add key="names", value="beam,column,girder"/>
</categories>
```

I created a function that will point to my `.config` file

```cs
public static List<string> GetCategorieNames()
{
     string path =Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;             
     Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
            
     categories section = appConfig.GetSection("categories") as categories;
     List<string> categoryList = new List<string>();     
     categoryList.AddRange(Array.ConvertAll(section.KeyName.Split(','), s => s.Trim()));

     return categoryList;
}
```

When I put a breakpoint and debug the appConfig variable, it's file path is pointing to the correct location that I want it to read data from. But when I continue to debug further, it contains sections from some other configuration document (not quite sure where).
What is the correct way to reference a `.config` file that is not the host application's?

Comment: Have a look at OpenMappedExeConfiguration instead of OpenExeConfiguration. For the "what is the correct way" part of your question. Correct is not having a dll.config but adding it to the exe.config.

Comment: Is your custom `categories` section present? Configuration files inherit. You may be seeing an aggregation of configuration sections and values. See ["OpenMappedExeConfiguration vs. OpenExeConfiguration"](https://9to5answer.com/openmappedexeconfiguration-vs-openexeconfiguration) for a sense of the difference between the two methods.

Comment: The .NET Framework .config files are still supported and can still be used but, in .NET, appsettings.json supersedes the app.config and per assembly configuration is out of favor.

Comment: Thank you Ralf and Jonathan-dodds, Both of these insights where helpful.